# How to handle status codes at the middleware level?

Tags: next.js, middleware

I receive negative **status codes** (500 code) from the backend on the client side,

I want to handle it on the **middleware** side.

How will it work?

If the status code == 500, then I redirect to the main page

But I can't figure out how to implement it.

I need a response

```
// middleware.ts
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

  if (pathname.startsWith(`/company/`)) {
    res.redirect([500], "/"); // incorrect variant, cause res haven't redirect
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use the res.writeHead to send a response with a specific status code and a Location header. You can then use the res.end to end the response.

Comment: @BrixxonTulabing actually, NextResponse haven't res.writeHead and res.end

Comment: Are you looking to intercept the response of a request in the middleware? That is not possible. On the other hand if you want to respond with specific headers or redirect, before request reaches the API route, that is possible

Comment: @TusharShahi I want to track what status code I receive and make a redirect depending on the status code, is it possible to do this in the middleware?